# Redirecting Input and Output in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working on a chatbot for my school assignment. I have finished the whole chatting part, using Scanner for user input and System.out.println() to display the conversation.
Now I want to implement a GUI for the chatbot. I have gotten a very simple GUI with a JTextField and JTextArea being the input box and display box respectively.

But now I am totally clueless on how to link them together. **It is like for Scanner, instead of System.in, will read the input from the JTextField and instead of displaying the output in console, display them in the JTextArea.**

Anyone can help me with this? Like what should I learn to implement to link the chatbot and GUI together?

If you want to take a look at my GUI code, it is below:

```
public class GUI_V2 extends JFrame {

private JTextField txtEnter = new JTextField();
//Chat area;
private JTextArea txtChat = new JTextArea();

//Scroll
private final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(txtChat);


public GUI_V2(){
    //Frame Attributes
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(2000,2000);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setTitle("Menu ChatBot");

    //textEnter Attributes
   txtEnter.setLocation(20,1825);
   txtEnter.setSize(1950,100);
   txtEnter.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,45));

    //txtChat Attributes
   txtChat.setLocation(22,5);
   txtChat.setSize(1950,1800);
   txtChat.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,45));
   txtChat.setBackground(java.awt.Color.getHSBColor(0.4957f,0.0902f,1.0f));
   txtChat.setLineWrap(true);
   txtChat.setWrapStyleWord(true);
   txtChat.setEditable(false);

   //scroll Attributes
   scroll.setLocation(22,5);
   scroll.setSize(1950,1800);

   //Add Items To Frame
   this.add(txtEnter);
   this.add(scroll);



   //txtEnter Action Event:
   txtEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
           //add userInput into the txtChat
           String uText = txtEnter.getText();
           txtChat.append("You" + ": " + uText + "\n");
           //auto scroll down
           txtChat.setCaretPosition(txtChat.getDocument().getLength());
           //set the txtEnter field to be empty
           txtEnter.setText("");
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: well, your input seems just right. sadly you don't show your output.

Comment: So you need to add JTextField value into JTextArea when button click or focus change or what?

Comment: No. The GUI is fine. I want to direct the output of my chatbot class to the GUI's JTextArea. And use JTextField's input as my chatbot's input

Answer (score 0):

Don't set layout to `null` and don't use `setLocation()` to arrange component, instead use a proper layout. Please refer [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

As a example for your scenario, you can use [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box)(this will not arrange your component properly because `BoxLayout` stretch component to available spaces):

Change:

```
this.setLayout(null);
```

To:

```
this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Also you need to add `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI_V2();
}
```

Since you have set to large sizes, you cannot see text in `JTextArea` without scroll to top.

One last thing, there is no actual need here to extend `JFrame`. I myself extend `JFrame` if I have to overide methods in `JFrame`. If you are not going to override methods, you can simply create object from `JFrame`.

This is how I do it:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUI_V2{

    public JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField txtEnter;
    //Chat area;
    private JTextArea txtChat;

    //Scroll
    private JScrollPane scroll;


    public GUI_V2(){
        initComp();
    }

    public void initComp(){
        frame = new JFrame("Menu ChatBot");
        frame.setLayout(new CardLayout());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(1000, 1000);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        txtEnter = new JTextField();
        //textEnter Attributes
        txtEnter.setSize(1000,100);
        txtEnter.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,45));
        panel.add(txtEnter, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        txtChat = new JTextArea();
        //txtChat Attributes
        txtChat.setSize(1000,900);
        txtChat.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,45));
        txtChat.setBackground(java.awt.Color.getHSBColor(0.4957f,0.0902f,1.0f));
        txtChat.setLineWrap(true);
        txtChat.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtChat.setEditable(false);

        scroll = new JScrollPane(txtChat);
        //scroll Attributes
        scroll.setSize(1000,900);
        panel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        doAction();
    }

    public void doAction(){
        //txtEnter Action Event:
        txtEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                //add userInput into the txtChat
                String uText = txtEnter.getText();
                txtChat.append("You" + ": " + uText + "\n");
                //auto scroll down
                txtChat.setCaretPosition(txtChat.getDocument().getLength());
                //set the txtEnter field to be empty
                txtEnter.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI_V2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting the errors for me. I am still very new to GUI. But the primary problem is how to redirect the output of my chatbot class (using system out print line) to the JTextArea. And direct the input from JTextField to my Scanner in my chatbox class

Comment: and what is the purpose of that. I cannot even understand properly what you are saying.